# Reading from a file rather than from the console

Tags: java, file-io

I am getting exception thrown and i think it has to with the `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` at the sub string and also do you think the below method would work for getting data passed to my array after parsing

I want this to be read from a txt file like this, on each line:

```
  1
  0
  1
  0
  0
  1
  0
```

ONE INTEGER PER LINE!!

```
String fileName = "input.txt";
File file = new File(fileName);
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
    data1 = scanner.nextLine();

}
for ( int i = 0; i < data1.length(); i++)
{
    covertDataArray[i] = Byte.parseByte(data1.substring( i, i+1));
}
```

This is previous working version but it reads from the console.   where it would be : 1010101001

```
System.out.println("Enter the binary bits");

data1 = in.next();


for ( int i = 0; i < data1.length(); i++)
{
    covertDataArray[i] = Byte.parseByte(data1.substring( i, i+1));
}
```

Comment: you can simply check by running it, right?

Comment: what exception is this throwing? `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading all the lines and only keeping the last in your `data1` variable. That's probably your problem.

You should, instead, handle each value right away while reading the file, and build an `ArrayList` instead of an array (because you won't know its size beforehand):

```
String fileName = "input.txt";
File file = new File(fileName);
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

ArrayList<Byte> covertDataList= new ArrayList<>();
while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
    String line = scanner.nextLine(); // the line should be just a number
    covertDataList.add(Byte.parseByte(line)); // no substring needed
}
```

If you want to fail nicely when the file format is wrong, you may surround `parseByte` with a `try`/`catch` block.

### About the ArrayList

If you want to use your list as an array, you can just:

- use `covertDataList.get(i)` instead of `covertDataArray[i]`
- use `covertDataList.set(i, value);` instead of `covertDataArray[i] = value;`

If you really need an array (I don't see the point here), you can do this:

```
Byte[] covertDataArray = covertDataList.toArray(new Byte[list.size()]);
```

Comment: it actually runs now no exception thrown however it only reads the first line and doesn't get to rest of the lines each line contains one integer either "1" or "0"

Comment: I would also change LHS ArrayList<Byte> to List<Byte>

Comment: @user3558924 are you talking about the code I provided, or yours?

Comment: @Greg I put `ArrayList` so that the OP could still use it as an array (index access), because I don't know what he does later with `covertDataArray`. But I agree if `get(i)` is not needed, then `List` is fine.

Comment: So mine,I can't use an array list it wont gel with the rest of my program

Comment: @user3558924 You can use `toArray()` afterwards.

Comment: @user3558924 I edited my post to show you how to do so.